# custom backgrounds?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I was looking at some UI elements for Android, I can't figure out how apps makes custom scrollable backgrounds (if they are backgrounds in the first place). Here is an example:

http://bergcloud.com/wp-content/themes/bergcloud/images/screenshots/2_choose.png

how would you go about making a list of those ripped of paper (ie. Daily Puzzle, Daily Weather, News).

My question is basically how would I go about making custom images as part of a list (and apply spacing between them)

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at [SimpleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html).
Basically all you need to do is to create an XML layout for your cell, which can have a custom background, some padding, etc... and then pass its resource ID as the 'resource' parameter in the adapter's constructor.

Depending on what data you want to populate your list with, you might need a different adapter, but the idea is the same.